# How to use my enums defined in my c# class file in MVC view page

Tags: c#

I have this enum defined in my c# class file in a seperate folder.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using TurnaroundManagement.DataServices.Context;
using TurnaroundManagement.DataServices.Entities;
using TurnaroundManagement.DataServices.Models;
using TurnaroundManagement.DataServices.Models.EntityModels;
using static TurnaroundManagement.DataServices.Models.CommonModels;

namespace TurnaroundManagement.DataServices.EntityModels
{
    public class OrdersModel
    {
        private TurnaroundManagementContext db = new TurnaroundManagementContext();
        private CommonModels objCommonModels = new CommonModels();



        public enum OrderStatus
        {
            Pending = 1,
            Processed = 2
        };
        public enum MaterialStatus
        {
            OnScheduleDate = 1,
            Delayed = 2,
            Issued = 3
        };
        public enum DeliveryStatus
        {
            Pending = 1,
            Delivered = 2
        };


        public List<Orders> GetAllOrders(int Status)
        {
            List<Orders> OrdersList = new List<Orders>();
            try
            {
                OrdersList = db.Orders.Where(x => x.Status == Status).ToList();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                objCommonModels.LogException(ex);
                OrdersList = null;
            }
            return OrdersList;
        }



    }
}
```

How do i use this in my view page ? I cant access them in my view page. i have more enums to access..
I tried using this

@using myproject.dataservices.models.myclassnamethathastheenumvariableinit;

@using static myproject.dataservices.models.myclassnamethathastheenumvariableinit;

@using myproject.dataservices.models;

Nothing above is working..

Comment: What is the namespace of MaterialStatus?

Comment: From `myclassnamethathastheenumvariableinit` i guess the enum is contained within a class and not directly within a namespace. You can only `using` namespaces and members of static classes (`using static`). Can you add the surrounding classes and namespaces to you question?

Comment: So you need to `@using TurnaroundManagement.DataServices.EntityModels` and to access it this way: `OrdersModel.OrderStatus.Pending`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only `using` namespaces and static classes. If you want to access an type, defined within an other class, as in your example. You can `using` the namespace, that contains the class (`TurnaroundManagement.DataServices.EntityModels`) in your case.

Then you need to use the complete type hirachy, to access a member of your enum. For example

```
var deliveryStatus = OrdersModel.DeliveryStatus.Pending
```

If you´re writing code within a type of that hirachy, you can omit parts of the path.

I personally only nest type, if the nested type is *not* intended, to be publically used. You can move your enums safely to their own files. This also helps other developers to find the files containing a specific type faster.